# How to Remove the empty row in a txt file with batch

Tags: batch-file

Need a bit of help with this and I do understand that with batch a empty row gets added to the end of the txt file

But I need to temporarily remove that so my next script can work

I have tried 3 different ways to make this work and can't figure it out

This is my script

```
@echo off

FOR %%i IN ("Toedit\Ready.txt") do (
findstr /V "^$" "%%i" >> "%%i.tmp"
    >>"%%i.tmp" echo  ,
    del "%%i"
    ren "%%i.tmp" "%%~nxi"
)
```

I have also tried doing this

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("Ready.txt") do (echo(%%a)>>~.txt
move /y  ~.txt "Ready.txt"
```

But the end result is the same

Here is my `Ready.txt` file content

```
"dfhg": [
   1,
   2,
   10,
   4,
   8,
   9,
   3,
   6,
   7,
   5
empty space
```

My Bad Results

```
"dfhg": [
   1,
   2,
   10,
   4,
   8,
   9,
   3,
   6,
   7,
   5
,
empty space
```

My Final Results

```
"dfhg": [
   1,
   2,
   10,
   4,
   8,
   9,
   3,
   6,
   7,
   5,
empty space
```

I understand that batch creates an empty space and I'm ok with that, but I really need it removed so I can add the `,`

Comment: No empty row is added to the end of the text file. Every Windows text file uses by default a Carriage Return and Line Feed pair to terminate a line. Those two hidden characters are being introduced by the `echo` command, not by the batch file. If you don't want them, do not use the `echo` command. There are plenty of questions already on this site which show you how you can write to a file with just a Unix LF terminator, or with no terminator at all, instead of with a CRLF pair. Your question does not indicate that you've made any attempt to find examples, or introduce any of their techniques.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q75073481.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "prevline="

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF DEFINED prevline ECHO !prevline!
 SET "prevline=%%e"
)
ECHO !prevline!,
)>"%outfile%"

FC "%filename1%" "%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

Simply hold the previous line in a variable, output it if the next line exists.

Finally, output the last line with a comma appended.

Caution : test thoroughly is the source file may contain symbols, especially `!` and `%`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first idea I thought of, it uses PowerShell and should remove the last line terminator, *(CRLF or LF)*.

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "$t = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(\".\Toedit\Ready.txt\"); [IO.File]::WriteAllText(\".\Toedit\Ready.txt\", $t.TrimEnd())"
```

With that line terminator removed, the first character `echo`ed to it, *(I'd assume, in this case, a comma)*, will be appended as the next visible character in the file, i.e. it would become `5,CRLF`, rather than your 'Bad Results' `5CRLF,CRLF`.